# How to resolve error that AxImp.exe is not found on Jenkins using Mono?

Tags: jenkins, mono, jenkins-plugins

I want to build a C# project on my Jenkins build server with Mono. I use Jenkins 2.60.2 and the MSBuild Plugin 1.27. The problem is I get this job-failing warning and error message:

```
Build started 08/11/2017 05:38:12.
Project "/jenkins-mono-slave/workspace/MyProject/MySolution.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "/jenkins-mono-slave/workspace/MyProject/MySolution.sln" (1) is building "/jenkins-mono-slave/workspace/MyProject/MySolution/MySolution.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2563,5): warning MSB3084: Task attempted to find "AxImp.exe" in two locations. 1) Under the "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/" processor specific directory which is generated based on SdkToolsPath 2) The x86 specific directory under "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/" which is specified by the SDKToolsPath property. You may be able to solve the problem by doing one of the following:  1) Set the "SDKToolsPath" property to the location of the Microsoft Windows SDK. [/jenkins-mono-slave/workspace/MyProject/MySolution/MySolution.csproj]
/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2563,5): error MSB3086: Task could not find "AxImp.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\NETFXSDK\4.7\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed [/jenkins-mono-slave/workspace/MyProject/MySolution/MySolution.csproj]
Done Building Project "/jenkins-mono-slave/workspace/MyProject/MySolution/MySolution.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "/jenkins-mono-slave/workspace/MyProject/MySolution.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"/jenkins-mono-slave/workspace/MyProject/MySolution.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"/jenkins-mono-slave/workspace/MyProject/MySolution/MySolution.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
(ResolveComReferences target) -> 
  /usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2563,5): warning MSB3084: Task attempted to find "AxImp.exe" in two locations. 1) Under the "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/" processor specific directory which is generated based on SdkToolsPath 2) The x86 specific directory under "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/" which is specified by the SDKToolsPath property. You may be able to solve the problem by doing one of the following:  1) Set the "SDKToolsPath" property to the location of the Microsoft Windows SDK. [/jenkins-mono-slave/workspace/MyProject/MySolution/MySolution.csproj]


"/jenkins-mono-slave/workspace/MyProject/MySolution.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"/jenkins-mono-slave/workspace/MyProject/MySolution/MySolution.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
(ResolveComReferences target) -> 
  /usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2563,5): error MSB3086: Task could not find "AxImp.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\NETFXSDK\4.7\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed [/jenkins-mono-slave/workspace/MyProject/MySolution/MySolution.csproj]

    1 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.75
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I found not that much, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923258/task-could-not-find-aximp-exe). There it is suggested to run the missing AxImp.exe once on the local machine once and commit the generated dlls to the build server. But this solution is specific to Windows. I only have my Linux environment (Jenkins + developer machine). Is there a solution for this and does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Actually no, in the end I don't use Mono anymore but a real Windows slave.