# Task could not find "AxImp.exe" using the SdkToolsPath under Ubuntu Linux with Mono project and Rider

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, mono, linux-mint, rider

I have a .NET Framework (not .NET Core) C# Selenium project. It works under Windows 8.1/10. 
I recently installed Rider in my new Ubuntu 18.04 instance. I installed Mono project using [this guide](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin) but Rider shows 2 problems, after opening it up:

```
15:01   Project 'selenium_IALB' load finished with warnings: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

15:01   Project 'MICE' load finished with warnings: Task could not find "AxImp.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "/usr/lib/mono/4.5/" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\NETFXSDK\4.7.1\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed at (2686:5)
```

I found few questions answered here of how to resolve that problem on Windows [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923258/task-could-not-find-aximp-exe) but it says to install Windows SDK... which is not allowed on Ubuntu i guess (as i found).

As it is shown on the screen below, i have problems with some classes (yellow warning sign). In code it looks like they are missing.

[image]

The question is if it is normal that i have that "AxImp.exe" problem under Ubuntu and if yes, how can i solve it? It also does not work on Linux Mint.

EDIT: I resolved the issue of missing reference to those "yellow signed" classes. I've just change their names in the solution folder (ie. helpers.cs -> Helpers.cs). However, missing "AxImp.exe" file is still a problem and the solution does not compile.

Comment: where you able to solve this?

Comment: unfortunately not. I have been forced, 'couse of this, to switch to Windows on my machine. Furthermore, our project will be switched to .net core so no problem in the future